# How do I pass data to a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

K guys, so I created this up/down vote script (basically like the one here on stackoverflow), and I'm trying to add some Ajax to it, so that the page doesn't reload everytime you vote.

I have two controllers, one called grinders, and one called votes. (Grinders are basically posts)

So here's the index of all the grinders (Looks like this ) [image: Screenshot.]

and here's the code to that page.

```
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Listing grinders</h1>

 <%= render(:partial => "grinders/grinders")%>
<br />

<%= link_to 'New grinder', new_grinder_path %>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is what I have in the views/grinders/_grinders.erb

```
<% @grinders.each do |grinder| %>

<div id="main">
    <div style="float:left; height:80px; width:50px">
        <div class='up'>
            <% form_for(@vote, :remote => true) do |u|%>
                <%= u.hidden_field :grinder_id, :value => grinder.id %>
                <%= u.hidden_field :choice, :value => "up" %>
                <%= image_submit_tag("http://i13.photobucket.com/albums/a287/Rickmasta185/arrow-small-green-up.png", :class => 'create') %>

            <% end %>  
        </div>
        <center><%= grinder.votes_sum %></center>
        <div class='down'>
            <% form_for(@vote, :remote => true) do |d|%>
                <%= d.hidden_field :grinder_id, :value => grinder.id %>
                <%= d.hidden_field :choice, :value => "down" %>
                <%= image_submit_tag("http://i13.photobucket.com/albums/a287/Rickmasta185/arrow-small-red-down.png", :class => 'create') %>
            <% end %>  
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class='box' >"<strong>It grinds our gears </strong><%=h grinder.grinder %>"</div>



 </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

But everytime I try to vote for one, I get the following error:

> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
>   You might have expected an instance of Array.
>   The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
>   [image: Screenshot of error.]
>   I've tried soo many things, and I just cannot get it  to work! (Larger screenshot - http://grab.by/7bgb)

Any help? If you need anymore information, just ask!

Comment: can you post your index action here ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For passing data to a partial, use the `locals` option.

```
<%= render(:partial => "grinders/grinders", :locals => {:grinders => @grinders})%>
```

And then in your partial, refer it as `grinders` and not `@grinders`.

However, since you are rendering a collection here, this is the idiomatic way of rendering a collection:

```
<%= render :collection => @grinders %>
```

This will look for a partial named 'grinder.erb' and the local variable that will be passed to the partial, would be `grinder` (Singular name for the collection). With this, you can actually get rid of the loop statement in your partial. You can also use a custom name, say `my_grinder`, and a local variable with the same name will be passed to the partial.

To know more, go through this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: In that case, @grinders might be empty. Can you inspect the `@grinders` object? (You can also update your question with code from the controller)

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 3 it is like this

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Products</h1>
<%= render :partial => 'product', :collection => @products %>
```

**_product.html.erb**

```
<p>Product Name: <%= product.name %></p>
```

When a partial is called with a pluralized collection, then the individual instances of the partial have access to the member of the collection being rendered via a variable named after the partial. In this case, the partial is _product, and within the _product partial, you can refer to product to get the instance that is being rendered

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%= render(:partial => "grinders/grinders", :object => @grinders) %>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Votes#create action is trying to process the "grinders/_grinders.html.erb" partial, which is weird because AJAX calls would likely only output JS or JSON.

Can you show us the content of the files:

1. app/views/votes/create.rjs.erb
2. app/controllers/votes_controller.rb (especially the create method)